# fail2ban does not send email when an IP is banned

Tags: linux, security, ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to configure fail2ban to get an email when an IP is banned.

I changed the jail.local config file. I changed the action parameter to action_mwl. I installed sendmail.

I receive emails when fail2ban is stopped or started but not when an IP is banned so the emails can be sent from the server.

What am I missing?

Thanks

```
mike@test:~$ sudo cat /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
# Fail2Ban configuration file.
#
# This file was composed for Debian systems from the original one
# provided now under /usr/share/doc/fail2ban/examples/jail.conf
# for additional examples.
#
# Comments: use '#' for comment lines and ';' for inline comments
#
# To avoid merges during upgrades DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE
# and rather provide your changes in /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
#

# The DEFAULT allows a global definition of the options. They can be overridden
# in each jail afterwards.

[DEFAULT]

# "ignoreip" can be an IP address, a CIDR mask or a DNS host. Fail2ban will not
# ban a host which matches an address in this list. Several addresses can be
# defined using space separator.
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8

# "bantime" is the number of seconds that a host is banned.
bantime  = 120

# A host is banned if it has generated "maxretry" during the last "findtime"
# seconds.
findtime = 600
maxretry = 3

# "backend" specifies the backend used to get files modification.
# Available options are "pyinotify", "gamin", "polling" and "auto".
# This option can be overridden in each jail as well.
#
# pyinotify: requires pyinotify (a file alteration monitor) to be installed.
#            If pyinotify is not installed, Fail2ban will use auto.
# gamin:     requires Gamin (a file alteration monitor) to be installed.
#            If Gamin is not installed, Fail2ban will use auto.
# polling:   uses a polling algorithm which does not require external libraries.
# auto:      will try to use the following backends, in order:
#            pyinotify, gamin, polling.
backend = auto

# "usedns" specifies if jails should trust hostnames in logs,
#   warn when reverse DNS lookups are performed, or ignore all hostnames in logs
#
# yes:   if a hostname is encountered, a reverse DNS lookup will be performed.
# warn:  if a hostname is encountered, a reverse DNS lookup will be performed,
#        but it will be logged as a warning.
# no:    if a hostname is encountered, will not be used for banning,
#        but it will be logged as info.
usedns = warn

#
# Destination email address used solely for the interpolations in
# jail.{conf,local} configuration files.
destemail = mike@test.com

#
# Name of the sender for mta actions
sendername = Fail2Ban

#
# ACTIONS
#

# Default banning action (e.g. iptables, iptables-new,
# iptables-multiport, shorewall, etc) It is used to define
# action_* variables. Can be overridden globally or per
# section within jail.local file
banaction = iptables-multiport

# email action. Since 0.8.1 upstream fail2ban uses sendmail
# MTA for the mailing. Change mta configuration parameter to mail
# if you want to revert to conventional 'mail'.
mta = sendmail

# Default protocol
protocol = tcp

# Specify chain where jumps would need to be added in iptables-* actions
chain = INPUT

#
# Action shortcuts. To be used to define action parameter

# The simplest action to take: ban only
action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]

# ban & send an e-mail with whois report to the destemail.
action_mw = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
              %(mta)s-whois[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s", sendername="%(sendername)s"]

# ban & send an e-mail with whois report and relevant log lines
# to the destemail.
action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
               %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s", sendername="%(sendername)s"]

# Choose default action.  To change, just override value of 'action' with the
# interpolation to the chosen action shortcut (e.g.  action_mw, action_mwl, etc) in jail.local
# globally (section [DEFAULT]) or per specific section
action = %(action_mwl)s

#
# JAILS
#

# Next jails corresponds to the standard configuration in Fail2ban 0.6 which
# was shipped in Debian. Enable any defined here jail by including
#
# [SECTION_NAME]
# enabled = true

#
# in /etc/fail2ban/jail.local.
#
# Optionally you may override any other parameter (e.g. banaction,
# action, port, logpath, etc) in that section within jail.local

[ssh]

enabled  = true
port     = 23222
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 4
```

Here is an extract of my fail2ban log, we see that an IP is banned but I did not get an email.

```
2014-07-03 05:14:01,418 fail2ban.server : INFO   Stopping all jails
2014-07-03 05:15:02,140 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh' stopped
2014-07-03 05:15:02,144 fail2ban.server : INFO   Exiting Fail2ban
2014-07-03 05:15:13,245 fail2ban.server : INFO   Changed logging target to /var/log/fail2ban.log for Fail2ban v0.8.11
2014-07-03 05:15:13,246 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Creating new jail 'ssh'
2014-07-03 05:15:13,270 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh' uses pyinotify
2014-07-03 05:15:13,294 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Initiated 'pyinotify' backend
2014-07-03 05:15:13,295 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Added logfile = /var/log/auth.log
2014-07-03 05:15:13,297 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set maxRetry = 4
2014-07-03 05:15:13,297 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set findtime = 600
2014-07-03 05:15:13,298 fail2ban.actions: INFO   Set banTime = 120
2014-07-03 05:15:13,344 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh' started
2014-07-03 05:16:13,533 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Ban x.x.x.x
2014-07-03 05:17:13,669 fail2ban.actions: INFO   [ssh] x.x.x.x already banned
2014-07-03 05:18:13,734 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Unban x.x.x.x
```

Comment: Can you send raw mails from command line via sendmail? Do you see the outgoing mail in the local MTA's log file? If yes, do you see it in the log file of the receiving MTA?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you find a solution?
@lxg I can send mails from via CLI just fine with the "mailx" command as described here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/send-a-test-mail-from-shell-using-local-installed-postfix-252049/

Comment: @perelin: Please ask a new question and refer to this one in the problem description.